# Restore system to shadow copy

Tags: windows-vista, system-restore, volume-shadow-copy

I have uninstalled a program that I do not want to have uninstall.

I have shadow copies of the entire disk so the files are there. How can I revert the entire system to a shadow copy?

I'm using Vista

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/What-is-System-Restore), assuming it created a checkpoint before you uninstalled the program.

Comment: But system restore does not restore software?

Comment: Yes it does.  It will restore your system to that point in time.  This means your entire system, so it's a tradeoff.  You might just want to re-install the software.

Comment: System Restore will not touch documents but it will restore all applications and their settings — that's what it was created for.

Answer (score 0):

If you goto the folder where the program was installed and right click on the folder you will see previous versions. From within there you can restore a particular state.

This may not make your program work as it is likely the installer installed items other than just files such as registry settings.

Comment: That would not make the program work so I hardly see at as a solution

Comment: IE the answer is you cant with shadow copies alone, your best bet is system restore if you have it, or reinstall (but I guess you cant do that otherwise you wouldnt be asking this question).

Comment: Out of interest what program was it?

Comment: Office enterprise... Nope, cant reinstall. Perhaps a combination of system restore and shadow copy?